# Linq to Sql - Update the correct Datacontext

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, datacontext

I'm adding new item with my linq with new DataContext Like that:

```
  using (DataContext db1 = new DataContext())
        {
            db1.Customers.InsertOnSubmit(c);
            db1.SubmitChanges();
        }
```

After the add, I make some changes in the profile in my code
and I can't Save it because I can't update that Profile beaucse I can't reach this DataContext any more.
Their is any way to do it without reloading the Data item again in the default DataContext?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no "default" `DataContext`. If you are still working with an item and need to commit changes, then you need to keep that data-context available. The only other option is to *attach* it to a different data-context, but ... messier:

```
someContext.Attach(obj, true); // true to note that it is dirty and needs saving
```